# Unexplainable, random CPU lock-ups

Tags: cpu, freeze, hardware-failure, acer-aspire

Hardware: `Acer Aspire XC-603g (stock hardware, no modifications)`

Almost a year ago, I asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/555631/) on AskUbuntu because I had thought that the problem was with my installation of Ubuntu. Though over the months, I've been slowly realizing that this problem is with the CPU, not my system.

Here's the most relevant part of the question.

> It seems like every time I leave this particular machine/system on for extended periods of time (see details at bottom), it will randomly kernel panic, crash, or just freeze completely. The longest uptime I've recorded is about 18 hours. This is probably the most pathetically unstable Linux distro (or machine?) I've ever run. Even my last installation of Windows Vista could run for at least 20 hours (albeit with a random 10-20 minute lock-up about 5 hours in).

I should clarify that at this point, I am no longer suffering kernel panics or crashes. I think this is (somehow) due to me moving my home partition onto an external drive. I dunno, it just hasn't happened ever since I did that. The *freezes* still happen, though, and they are at a level below the kernel.

Here's my update on the question from today:

> Update: After nearly a year of dealing with this, I've been slowly pinpointing the cause of this problem. Turns out, it's not Ubuntu. It can't be Ubuntu. It just looks like it is because my use of the Windows partition pales dramatically in comparison to my use of the Ubuntu partition. I'm sure that if I used Windows for long enough, it, too, would lock up eventually.
>
> It's the CPU. I figured this out a few months ago when I started running scripts during my sessions to log what's going on, as well as setting up my magic key for being able to perform the beloved SysRQ + REISUB combo. Not only did all logs, including those dumped by the kernel, end abruptly in the event of a freeze, but the kernel wouldn't respond to any magic keys. Temperature is normal. Sound will loop like an N64 game when it freezes. Actually, the freeze is very similar to an NES/SNES/N64 freeze. Everything is normal, as if no freeze ever occurred, yet everything just abruptly stops in time. In short, somehow, the CPU is getting locked up.

I am still stumped. Is there some way I can prevent these freezes from happening? I'm really sick of this happening, and I'm sick of not being able to use software like vim and dwm to their full potential due to the messed up defensive habits I'm having to develop to counter the lockups. I would like to avoid resorting to getting another PC, if possible. I'll even dabble in over/underclocking if necessary.

How about it, folks. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you done any low-level hardware tests?

Comment: I would move to new hardware and put this issue to rest.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq No. How can I do that? Remember that this is happening *below* the kernel.

Comment: Well https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Memtest would be a start, as well as CPU https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=CPU+Test